# move random matrix 8*8

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, while-loop

I tried to implement Vacuum Cleaner move random,The direction of the movement should be in a array-list, so each time the machine should choose randomly 3 orientation from the list as a direction example(N,N,S). The machine will move according to the direction continually until it reach the edge it should choose again.

The problem that the machine not change the direction when reach the edge.

I write this method, is responsible to decide if the machine reach the edge:

```
public boolean Wall(int x, int y) {

    if (choices.contains("N") && y == 7) {
        return false;
    } else if (choices.contains("S") && y == 0) {
        return false;
    } else if (choices.contains("W") && x == 0) {
        return false;
    } else if (choices.contains("E") && x == 7) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and I call wall(), inside move().

This my all code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class test {

private static String[][] board;
private static final int ROWS = 8;
private static final int COLUMNS = 8;
int moves = 0;
List<String> orientation = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"N", "E", "W", "S"});
List<String> choices = new ArrayList<String>(3);


public test() {
    //String state = "d";
    board = new String[ROWS][COLUMNS];
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
            board[i][j] = " ";

        }
    }
    board[4][4] = "d";
    board[0][2] = "d";
    board[4][7] = "d";
    board[1][5] = "d";
    board[6][6] = "d";
    board[4][0] = "d";
}

public String toString() {
    String r = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
            r += "[" + board[i][j] + "]";
        }
        r += "\n";
    }
    return r;
}

public int[] gostright(int x, int y) {
    if (choices.contains("N")) {
        x--;
        if (x == -1) {
            x = 0;
        }

    } else if (choices.contains("W")) {
        y--;
        if (y == -1) {
            y = 0;
        }

    } else if (choices.contains("S")) {
        x++;
        if (x == 8) {
            x = 7;
        }
    } else if (choices.contains("E")) {
        y++;
        if (y == 8) {
            y = 7;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("choise taste equal" + x + ":" + y);
    return new int[]{x, y};
}

public boolean Wall(int x, int y) {

    if (choices.contains("N") && y == 7) {
        return false;
    } else if (choices.contains("S") && y == 0) {
        return false;
    } else if (choices.contains("W") && x == 0) {
        return false;
    } else if (choices.contains("E") && x == 7) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public int CountDirt() {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == "d") {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    // System.out.println("the found dirt " + count+" dirts");
    return count;
}

public void Move() {
    Collections.shuffle(orientation);
    int nowX = 4, nowY = 4;
    int counter = 0;
    int strightCounter = 1;
    int wallx = 0;
    int wally = 0;
    while (CountDirt() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            choices.add(orientation.get(i));
            for (int x = 0; x < strightCounter; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < strightCounter; y++) {
                   if(Wall(wallx,wally))  {
                       break;
                   }              

                    System.out.println("Wall" + x + ":" + y);
                    board[nowX][nowY] = "1";
                    int[] pos = gostright(nowX, nowY);
                    nowX = pos[0];
                    nowY = pos[1];
                    System.out.println("" + nowX + ":" + nowY);
                    System.out.println("nowX and nowY" + board[nowX][nowY]);
                    board[nowX][nowY] = "#";
                    moves++;
                    System.out.println(toString());
                    System.out.println(orientation.get(i));
                    System.out.println("Choices " + choices);
                    System.out.println("# move" + moves);
                }
            }
            counter++;
            System.out.println("CountDirt()==" + CountDirt());


        }
        choices.clear();

    }

}
```

I Think the problem in move(),  But not sure where is it Exactly.

Comment: cross-posted here: [www.java-forums.org: help-vacuum-cleaner-code](http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/52123-help-vacuum-cleaner-code.html)

Answer (score 0):

I only see `wallx` appeared in this code for twice. `int wallx = 0;` and `if(Wall(wallx,wally))`. This means you are always passing 0 and 0 to the Wall().